# Change Xamarin.Forms button clicked colour

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms UWP application and I wanted to change my button's background colour when pressed. I have been searching the web and the most straightforward way I could find is this:

```
 private void Button_OnClicked(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = (Button) s;
        var originalColour = b.BackgroundColor;
        b.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkOrange;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25), () =>
        {
            b.BackgroundColor = originalColour;
            return false;
        });
    }
```

However, personally, I am not liking this approach very much. How can this be done better?

Comment: Simply edit button press state in button template

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, is that possible in Xamarin Forms? According to my research, it is not currently possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An [EventTrigger](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/#Event_Triggers) solution in XAML:

Implement the following in `MyAssembly`, e.g. the portable assembly containing App.xaml:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class ButtonTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
  {
    public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement visual)
    {
        var button = visual as Button;
        if (button == null) return;
        if (BackgroundColor != null) button.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
    }
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
...
<Button Text="EventTrigger">
  <Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="Pressed">
      <local:ButtonTriggerAction BackgroundColor="Red" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger Event="Released">
      <local:ButtonTriggerAction BackgroundColor="Default" />
    </EventTrigger>
  </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: That is awesome! Very straightforward, easy to implement and not having me to even edit the UWP project. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

a more natural and cleaner way to do it would be using `VisualStateManager`

```
<Button Text="Click Me!">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Button>
```

you can read more about in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager).

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution but of course not very clean.

THe problem here is that each platform implements the "pressed" state differently and Xamarin.Forms doesn't have any built-in way how to handle this.

In case of UWP, you have two options. First, you can create a new default button style that will be used throughout your app. You can find the default [style here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx), and just copy it, modify the `Pressed` `VisualState` and add is as a default resource:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
   <!-- ... your style -->
</Style>
```

However, if the pressed button color should be applied only in some places, you should rather create a new view that derives from button and uses a custom renderer on UWP that applies a custom style in the `OnElementChanged` event handler:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (this.Element != null)
    {
        this.Control.Style = ( Style )Application.Current.Resources["CustomButtonStyle"];
    }
}
```

Other platforms will have similar solutions as well, but you will definitely have to implement them in such platform-specific way, probably using the custom renderers.

For more information on custom renderers [see the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). You may also find some inspiration in [Xamarin.Forms Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the pointers you mentioned above are a great start. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Hope it helps :-) . Happy coding!